# How to get the list of verbs installed on winetricks

Tags: wine, winetricks

How can I check which verbs are installed on my wine prefix?

I want to list only the installed ones. For example, on apt package manager, I can type `apt list --installed` to display the installed packages. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most other programs on Linux and similar systems, appending `--help` when running them will print an overview of the possible things you can pass it. So you can search for the string `verbs` in its output:

```
$ winetricks --help | grep verbs
Executes given verbs.  Each verb installs an application or changes a setting.
    --verify          Run (automated) GUI tests for verbs, if available
list-all              list all categories and their verbs
apps list             list verbs in category 'applications'
benchmarks list       list verbs in category 'benchmarks'
dlls list             list verbs in category 'dlls'
fonts list            list verbs in category 'fonts'
games list            list verbs in category 'games'
settings list         list verbs in category 'settings'
list-cached           list cached-and-ready-to-install verbs
list-download         list verbs which download automatically
list-manual-download  list verbs which download with some help from the user
list-installed        list already-installed verbs
```

As you can see, one of the options is the command to "`list all categories and their verbs`", so try that:

```
winetricks list-all
```

There's also a lot of other things that start with `list al…`, and what you now after your edit ask for in the question is also amongst these:

```
winetricks list-installed
```